# Super slow execution in foreach loop

Tags: php, database, foreach, pdo, game-engine

i have an online game script based on php .
The game is about wars and stuff , when a a player execute a war task it stored in db with end time and threads details

Now when tasks number below 100 , everything is cool and no issues happen
But when for example 10 players sent 100 war tasks that supposed to end at same time , here where the issue occurs
The execution get delayed which makes them be in top of each other and causes a lot of issues

The task must be executed without any delay whenever it ends

This is the code :

```
public function processTaskQueue($type, $playerId)
    {
        $p_type = QS_ACCOUNT_DELETE . ',' . QS_MERCHANT_GO . ',' . QS_MERCHANT_BACK . ',' . QS_WAR_REINFORCE . ',' . QS_WAR_ATTACK . ',' . QS_WAR_ATTACK_PLUNDER . ',' . QS_WAR_ATTACK_SPY . ',' . QS_CREATEVILLAGE . ',' . QS_TATAR_RAISE . ',' . QS_SITE_RESET . ',' . QS_CROP_DELETE . ',' . QS_ARTEFACTS_RAISE;
        if ($type == 1) {
            $expr = "((q.player_id=" . $playerId . " AND q.proc_type!=" . QS_TROOP_TRAINING . ") OR q.proc_type IN (" . $p_type . "))";
        } elseif ($type == 2) {
            $expr = "(q.player_id=" . $playerId . " OR q.proc_type IN (" . $p_type . "))";
        } else {
            $expr = "q.proc_type!=" . QS_TROOP_TRAINING;
        }
        $result = db::get_all("SELECT  q.id, q.player_id, q.village_id, q.to_player_id, q.to_village_id, q.proc_type, q.building_id, q.proc_params, q.threads, q.execution_time, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),q.end_date) remainingTimeInSeconds FROM p_queue q WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),(q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) SECOND)) <= 0 AND $expr ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),(q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) SECOND)) ASC");
        foreach ($result as $resultRow) {
            $remain = $resultRow['remainingTimeInSeconds'];
            if ($remain < 0) {
                $remain = 0;
            }
            $resultRow['threads_completed_num'] = $resultRow['execution_time'] <= 0 ? $resultRow['threads'] : floor(($resultRow['threads'] * $resultRow['execution_time'] - $remain) / $resultRow['execution_time']);
            if ($this->processTask($resultRow)) {
                unset($result);
                $this->processQueue($type, $playerId);
                break;
            }
        }
        unset($result);

    }
```

Can someone help me ?

Updated ::

```
public function processQueue($type = 3, $playerId = 0)
    {
        global $gameConfig;
        $this->load_model('Mutex', 'mutex');
        $this->mutex->releaseOnTimeout();
        if ($this->mutex->lock()) {
            $this->processTaskQueue($type, $playerId);
            $row = db::get_row("SELECT gs.cur_week w1, CEIL((TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(gs.start_date))/2) w2 FROM g_settings gs");
            if (($row['w2'] - $row['w1']) >= 1) {
                db::query("UPDATE g_settings gs SET gs.cur_week=:cur", array(
                    'cur' => intval($row['w2'])
                ));
                /*$allP = db::get_all("SELECT p.id FROM p_players p WHERE p.total_people_count>5000 ");
                $Ids2 = "";
                foreach($allP as $Ids)
                {
                    $Ids2 .= ($Ids2 == "" ) ? $Ids['id'] : ",".$Ids['id'];
                }
                $Ids2 = "(".$Ids2.")";
                db2::query("UPDATE p_players p SET p.gold_num=p.gold_num+:gold WHERE p.is_active=1 and p.id IN $Ids2",array('gold' => $gameConfig['settings']['freegold2']));*/
                $this->setWeeklyMedals(intval($row['w2']));
            }
            $this->mutex->release();
        }
    }

public function processTask($taskRow)
    {
        $customAction = FALSE;
        switch ($taskRow['proc_type']) {
            case QS_ACCOUNT_DELETE:
                {
                    $this->deletePlayer($taskRow['player_id']);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_BUILD_CREATEUPGRADE:
                {
                    $customAction = $this->executeBuildingTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_BUILD_DROP:
                {
                    $customAction = $this->executeBuildingDropTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_TROOP_RESEARCH:
                {
                }
            case QS_TROOP_UPGRADE_ATTACK:
                {
                }
            case QS_TROOP_UPGRADE_DEFENSE:
                {
                    $this->executeTroopUpgradeTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_TROOP_TRAINING:
                {
                    $this->executeTroopTrainingTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_TROOP_TRAINING_HERO:
                {
                    $this->executeHeroTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_TOWNHALL_CELEBRATION:
                {
                    $this->executeCelebrationTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_MERCHANT_GO:
                {
                    $customAction = $this->executeMerchantTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_MERCHANT_BACK:
                {
                    if ($taskRow['building_id'] >= 1) {
                        $this->returnMerchantTask($taskRow);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case QS_WAR_REINFORCE:
                {
                }
            case QS_WAR_ATTACK:
                {
                }
            case QS_WAR_ATTACK_PLUNDER:
                {
                }
            case QS_WAR_ATTACK_SPY:
                {
                }
            case QS_CREATEVILLAGE:
                {
                    $customAction = $this->executeWarTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_LEAVEOASIS:
                {
                    $this->executeLeaveOasisTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_PLUS1:
                {
                    db::query('UPDATE p_players p SET p.active_plus_account=0 WHERE p.id=:id', array(
                        'id' => intval($taskRow['player_id'])
                    ));
                    break;
                }
            case QS_PLUS2:
                {
                    $this->executePlusTask($taskRow, 1);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_PLUS3:
                {
                    $this->executePlusTask($taskRow, 2);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_PLUS4:
                {
                    $this->executePlusTask($taskRow, 3);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_PLUS5:
                {
                    $this->executePlusTask($taskRow, 4);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_TATAR_RAISE:
                {
                    $this->load_model('Artefacts', 'A');
                    $this->A->createTatarVillages();
                    break;
                }
            case QS_SITE_RESET:
                {
                    $this->load_model('Install', 'm');
                    $this->m->processSetup($GLOBALS['SetupMetadata']['map_size']);
                    $customAction = TRUE;

                    break;
                }
            case QS_CROP_DELETE:
                {
                    $this->load_model('Crop', 'c');
                    $customAction = $this->c->deleteCrop($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_ARTEFACTS_RAISE:
                {
                    $this->load_model('Artefacts', 'A');
                    $this->A->createArtefacts();
                    break;
                }
        }
        if (!$customAction) {
            $remaining_thread = $taskRow['threads'] - $taskRow['threads_completed_num'];
            if ($remaining_thread <= 0) {
                db::query("DELETE FROM p_queue WHERE id=:id", array(
                    'id' => intval($taskRow['id'])
                ));
            } else {
                db::query("UPDATE p_queue q SET q.threads=:th WHERE q.id=:id", array(
                    'th' => intval($remaining_thread),
                    'id' => intval($taskRow['id'])
                ));
            }
        }
        return $customAction;
    }
```

Comment: Your loop appears to be running several database queries in each iteration. You're going to need to either set up a separate Queue that can run on its own process to handle this, or you're going to have to look into something like Stored Procedures to optimize this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you kind replay .yes each server of the game is a separate  db , i do not know any other way to make a code running the game for each server in another way ( i am not an expert ) . about Stored Procedures to optimize , how can i do it ?